# How can I get the value of the selected radio button?

Tags: lightning-web-components, table, radio-button

I want to get the value of the selected radio button, i tried it through the function `handleRadioChange(event)`, but I'm recieving that `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`.

I tried too `this.selectedItem = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;`, but failed...

Is there a property like `ischecked` or something? What can I do?

**.HTML**

```
<template>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_medium">TITLE</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-title">SUB</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-lookup" data-select="multi" data-scope="single" data-typeahead="true">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-top_medium slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <button
                                class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right searchButtonStyle">
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:search" variant="bare"
                                    alternative-text="Search" aria-hidden="true" onclick={handleSearch}>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </button>
                            <input type="text" id="lookup" class="slds-input" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant=""
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                                aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="Search..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover" role="listbox"
                        id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th key={col} for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                                    {col}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr key={row.id} template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                                <td class="slds-text-align_left">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                        <input type="radio" onchange = {handleRadioChange} id={row.id} value={row} name="default"/>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.postalcode}>{row.postalcode}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.street}>{row.street}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.number}>{row.number}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={compl.name}>{compl.name}</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral">New Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>
```

**.JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin";

export default class ModalLwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track columns = ["", "COLLUMN1", "COLLUMN2", "COLLUMN3", "COLLUMN4"];
  @track rows;
  @track selectedItem;

  _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
  _actionUtilClass;

  connectedCallback() {
    this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
  }

  @api
  callModal(addressesResponse) {
    this.rows = addressesResponse;
  }

  get options() {
    return [{ label: "", value: row }];
  }

  handleRadioChange(event) {
    this.selectedItem = event.detail.value;
  }
}
```

**addressesResponse model**

```
 [
  { id: 0, postalcode: '1234', street: 'ABC', number: '1', name: 'XYZ 3, CDE TR, AAA5' },
  { id: 1, postalcode: '2222', street: 'BBB', number: '2', name: 'NDP 3, DDD FR' },
  { id: 2, postalcode: '1111', street: 'DAE', number: '003', name: 'R5' },
];
```

**The result**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

id attributes are usually changed in lightning. You can use another attribute probably `accessKey` or any other `data-attribute` that could tell you which row was actually checked.
You can maintain it as a property (isChecked) in your rows class variable.

.html

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover" role="listbox"
        id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th key={col} for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                    {col}
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                <tr key={row.id}>
                    <td class="slds-text-align_left">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                            <input type="radio" onchange={handleRadioChange} accesskey={row.id} value={row.isChecked} name="default"/>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.postalcode}>{row.postalcode}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.street}>{row.street}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.number}>{row.number}</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.name}>{row.name}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

.js

```
export default class App extends LightningElement {
  rows = [
  { id: 0, postalcode: '1234', street: 'ABC', number: '1', name: 'XYZ 3, CDE TR, AAA5' },
  { id: 1, postalcode: '2222', street: 'BBB', number: '2', name: 'NDP 3, DDD FR' },
  { id: 2, postalcode: '1111', street: 'DAE', number: '003', name: 'R5' },
  ];
  columns = ["", "COLLUMN1", "COLLUMN2", "COLLUMN3", "COLLUMN4"];
  selectedItem;
  handleRadioChange(event){
    const { accessKey } = event.target;
    this.rows = this.rows.map(row => ({ ...row, isChecked: accessKey == row.id }));
  }
}
```

Now you can get selected Item anywhere, just do

```
const selectedItem = this.rows.find(row => row.isChecked);
```

I used your code just modified few things. You can also see it in action [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/yCePPb3mlgRU5bTbN6Hp) in the playground.

Comment: Can you explain the logic? I'm begginer... So `isChecked: accessKey == row.id` mean if `accessKey == row.id`, so `isChecked = true`?

Comment: Correct, we're updating isChecked property for the selected row to true. I used == since the id is a number & dom attributes are always returned as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Why you do not use `lightning-input type="checkbox"`

Like this :

```
<lightning-input type="checkbox" onchange={handleCheckBoxChange} value={row.checked} data-id={row.id} label="Basic option"></lightning-input>
```

And JS :

```
handleCheckBoxChange(event){
    this.rows.forEach( row => {
        row.checked = row.id === event.currentTarget.dataset.id
    });
    this.selectedItem = this.rows.find(row => row.id === event.currentTarget.dataset.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to access by `value = {row.id}`

```
     <input type="radio" onchange = {handleRadioChange} id={row.id} value={row.id} name="default"/>
```

```
    handleRadioChange(event) {
        this.selectedItem = event.target.value;
      }
```