# Why does the radio button has checked = false , but is selected on screen?

Tags: lightning-web-components, event, table, radio-button

Why when I select a radio button option do I have `checked = false` ?

i guess it's why `checked` and `onchange` are working at the same time...but i don't know what to do because I need both.

EDIT: I tried  `this.checked = event.target.checked;` in `handleRadioChange` but its not working...

**Console.log**

```
checked false
```

**.HTML**

```
<template>
   <template if:true={openmodal}>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open slds-modal_large" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>
            </button>
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 class="slds-text-heading_medium">TITLE</h1>
                <h2 class="slds-text-title">SUB</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-lookup" data-select="multi" data-scope="single" data-typeahead="true">
                    <div class="slds-form-element slds-p-top_medium slds-p-horizontal_medium slds-m-bottom_small">
                        <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
                            <button
                                class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right searchButtonStyle">
                                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:search" variant="bare"
                                    alternative-text="Search" aria-hidden="true" onclick={handleSearch}>
                                </lightning-button-icon>
                            </button>
                            <input type="text" id="lookup" class="slds-input" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant=""
                                aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="lookup-grouped-table-id-1"
                                aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-expanded="true" placeholder="Search..." />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover" role="listbox"
                        id="lookup-grouped-table-id-1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th key={col} for:each={columns} for:item="col">
                                    {col}
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            <tr key={row.id} template for:each={rows} for:item="row">
                                <td class="slds-text-align_left">
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                                       <input type="radio"  checked={checked}  onchange={handleRadioChange}  value={row.id} id={row.id} name="default" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.postalcode}>{row.postalcode}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.street}>{row.street}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={row.number}>{row.number}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate" title={compl.name}>{compl.name}</div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer slds-modal__footer_directional">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close">Cancel</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" disabled = {disableButton} >New Account</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
   </template>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" role="presentation"></div>
</template>
```

**.JS**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin";

export default class ModalLwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
  @track columns = ["", "COLLUMN1", "COLLUMN2", "COLLUMN3", "COLLUMN4"];
  @track openmodal;
  @track rows;
  @track disableButton;
  @track checked = false;

  _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
  _actionUtilClass;

  connectedCallback() {
    this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
  }

  @api
  callModal(addressesResponse) {
    this.rows = addressesResponse;
    this.openModal = true;

  }

  handleRadioChange(event) {
    this.selectedItem = event.target.value;
    this.handleDisableButton();
  }

  handleDisableButton(){
      
      if (this.checked) {
      console.log("checked true");
      this.disableButton = false;
    }else{
      console.log("checked false");
      this.disableButton = true;
    }

    resetRadioButton() {
       this.checked = false;   
    }
}
```

**addressesResponse model**

```
 [
  { id: 0, postalcode: '1234', street: 'ABC', number: '1', name: 'XYZ 3, CDE TR, AAA5' },
  { id: 1, postalcode: '2222', street: 'BBB', number: '2', name: 'NDP 3, DDD FR' },
  { id: 2, postalcode: '1111', street: 'DAE', number: '003', name: 'R5' },
];
```

**result**
[image]

Comment: by using checked={checked} in your iteration, you are assigning the same prop to all your radio buttons, is this what you want?

Comment: @glls sorry, what did you mean specifically by prop? I will differentiate them from `value = {row.id}`. I want only one radio button checked and it's happening on the screen...but i'm getting checked = false...

Comment: How can I edit `event.target.checked `?

Comment: you should probably re-evaluate your approach, some answers already provided in https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367928/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-the-selected-radio-button seemed to point you in the right direction. for example, modify your row json and use map to mutate your rows array when selecting a button, check against a data property to know what row to update, your template will re-render with the button "checked". go through what Sachin Hooda posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Your usage of the "checked" and "disabled" attributes is incorrect

#### The longer version

In HTML, the "checked" attribute is used to set the default/initial value of a checkbox or radio button. It doesn't tell you whether or not the input has been selected or checked.

It's a "boolean attribute", but it's not meant to take a true/false value (i.e. `checked="true"`, like we might expect). Rather, the HTML spec says that just having a "boolean attribute" present in a tag makes it count as being true (i.e. `<input checked>` = checked is true, and `<input>` = checked is false).

I got this information from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24588399/901352), and the two supporting links to the HTML 5 spec are:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-checked
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

#### Other things worth noting

In your Javascript event handler, `event.target.checked` gives you the Boolean true/false value that we as programmers usually expect for checkboxes and radio buttons.

The "disabled" attribute on your "New Account" button is also an HTML "boolean attribute". You likely do not want to set that attribute in the HTML, doing so means your button is permanently disabled.

You probably want to remove the `checked={checked}` and `disabled={disableButton}` from your markup entirely.

If you want to grab a checked/selected value, you should probably use `this.template.querySelectorAll(':checked');` (using the CSS pseudo-class to find the elements you're looking for)

Comment: Thanks! To use `this.template.querySelectorAll(':checked');`, should I put something in the html? Like `<input checked type=radio>` ?

Comment: @Caroline No. The "checked" attribute in the tag is separate from whether or not a checkbox or radio button is selected (i.e. whether or not `event.target.checked` will be true or false). The W3C certainly didn't do us any favors by using the same label for 2 different behaviors. Like I said in my answer, including the "checked" attribute only sets the default state when the page is rendered.